# Get maximal value per Azure Data Explorer table from tables with same schema

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have multiple tables with telemetry Metric_1, Metric_2, Metric_3 and all those tables have the same schema (e.g. they contain Timestamp column). I'd like to get the most recent timestamp per table.
I found possibility of using union wildcard, but query

```
union Metric_*
|summarize Max= max(Timestamp)
```

never actually finished.

Query

```
Metric_1
|top 1 by Timestamp
```

takes no time. But even summarize on a single table takes forever (I killed it after 2 minutes)

```
Metric_1
|summarize Max= max(Timestamp)
```

Can you explain the time difference and suggest how to accomplish what I need? The outcome should be

```
Table    | MaxTimestamp
Metric_1 | Date1
Metric_2 | Date2
Metric_3 | Date3
```

Comment: `union Metric_*
|summarize Max= max(Timestamp)` and `Metric_1
|summarize Max= max(Timestamp)` works fine for me. (However, when adding aggregation by the source table, it does look sub-optimal). Please share a Client request ID of one of your queries.

Comment: It is kind of strange. I now focus on 2 tables. 1 has 800.000.000 rows and Metric_1
|summarize Max= max(Timestamp) works just fine (~1-2 sec). Then I have second table with 12.000.000.000 rows and I killed the query after 2 minutes. 
top 1 by Timestamp works on both tables within 1-2 secs). So I think the key question is, why on larger table is the summarize so slow. Request ID of the long running query: KustoWebV2;29d9f0e1-58ea-4010-89bd-1b60add31b25

Comment: Are you sure we are dealing with tables (and not functions)?

Comment: Yes, definitely with tables :)